# why performance improvement of CPU-intensive task differs between windows and linux when using multi processes

Tags: linux, multithreading, performance

Here is my situation:
my company need to run tests on tons of test samples. But if we start a single process on a windows PC machine, this test could last for hours, even days. so we try to split the test set and start a process to test each one of the slices on a multi-core linux server.

we expect **a linear performance improvement** for the server solution, but the truth is we could only observe a **2~3 times improvement** when the test task finished by **10~20 processes.**

I tried several means to locate the problem:

1. disable hyper-threading;
2. use max-performance power policy
3. use taskset to pin each process on different core

but no luck, the problem remains.

Why does this happen? which is the root cause, our code, OS or hardware?

here is the info of my pc and server:

- PC: os: win10; cpu: i5-4570, 2 physical core; mem : 16gb
- server: os: redhat 6.5 cpu: E5-2630 v3, 2 physical core; mem : 32gb

#### Edit:

About CPU: the server has 2 processors, and each of them has 8 physical cores. check [this link](http://ark.intel.com/products/83356/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2630-v3-20M-Cache-2_40-GHz) for more information.

About My Test: it's handwriting recognition related(that's why it's a cpu-sensitive task).

About IO: the performance check points do not involve much IO if logging doesn't count.

Comment: This questions is a bit broad.  But...  there must be some shared resource between the linux processes, that everything is contending for on this box.

Comment: What are the specifics of what you're trying to do, and why do you expect a linear improvement?  Especially given *2 physical core* on the server.

Comment: Do these tests read files? Get data from somewhere? Write output somewhere?

Comment: [ARK Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/83356/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2630-v3-20M-Cache-2_40-GHz) for this processor is showing 8 cores, did you mean to say that you have two physical processors, instead of cores?

Comment: will a bad-coding recursive function be the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

> we expect a linear performance improvement for the server solution,
>   but the truth is we could only observe a 2~3 times improvement when
>   the test task finished by 10~20 processes.

This seems very logical considering there are only 2 cores on the system. Starting 10-20 processes will only add some overhead due to task switching.

Also, I/O could be a bottleneck here too, if multiple processes are reading from disk at the same time.

Ideally, the number of running threads should not exceed 2 x the number of cores.